# The short name of a USA state by its full name (the gems countries and country_select)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-2.1

I'm using 2 gems for the countries and their states (the USA and Canada):

```
gem "countries"
gem "country_select"
```

Say I'm using only `USA` for simplicity and I have the state `California`. I want to get the short name for it which is CA. I can do this by the very straightforward way by iterating over the all the states. But there may be the standard method for this.

So does it exist? If not is there a simple way?

Answer (score 2):

Iteration seems like the simplest method since `countries` has State Select as a TODO.

```
 {"Alabama"=>"AL", "Alaska"=>"AK", "Arizona"=>"AZ", "Arkansas"=>"AR","California"=>"CA",
  "Colorado"=>"CO", "Connecticut"=>"CT", "Delaware"=>"DE", "District of Columbia"=>"DC",
  "Florida"=>"FL", "Georgia"=>"GA", "Hawaii"=>"HI", "Idaho"=>"ID", "Illinois"=>"IL",
  "Indiana"=>"IN", "Iowa"=>"IA","Kansas"=>"KS", "Kentucky"=>"KY", "Louisiana"=>"LA",
  "Maine"=>"ME","Maryland"=>"MD", "Massachusetts"=>"MA", "Michigan"=>"MI", "Minnesota"=>"MN",
  "Mississippi"=>"MS", "Missouri"=>"MO", "Montana"=>"MT","Nebraska"=>"NE", "Nevada"=>"NV",
  "New Hampshire"=>"NH", "NewJersey"=>"NJ", "New Mexico"=>"NM", "New York"=>"NY",
  "North Carolina"=>"NC", "North Dakota"=>"ND", "Ohio"=>"OH", "Oklahoma"=>"OK",
  "Oregon"=>"OR", "Pennsylvania"=>"PA", "Puerto Rico"=>"PR", "Rhode Island"=>"RI",
  "South Carolina"=>"SC", "South Dakota"=>"SD", "Tennessee"=>"TN", "Texas"=>"TX",
  "Utah"=>"UT", "Vermont"=>"VT", "Virginia"=>"VA", "Washington"=>"WA", "West Virginia"=>"WV",
  "Wisconsin"=>"WI", "Wyoming"=>"WY"}
```

That is a `Hash` of all the states (Does not include military bases) Otherwise maybe take a look at [Carmen](https://github.com/jim/carmen)